# Why isn't this command taking the diff of two directories?

Tags: perl, diff, command

I am asked to diff two directories using Perl but I think something is wrong with my command,

```
$diff = system("sudo diff -r '/Volumes/$vol1' '/Volumes/$vol2\\ 1/' >> $diff.txt");
```

It doesn't display and output. Can someone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: I suspect the directory names. Please post them.

Comment: "I am asked" -- is this homework?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you want to store all differences in a string.

If this is the case, the command in the question is not going to work for a few reasons:

- It's hard to tell whether it's intended or not, but the `$diff` variable is being used to set the filename storing the differences. Perhaps this should be `diff.txt`, not `$diff.txt`
- The result of the `diff` command is saved in `$diff.txt`. It doesn't display anything in STDOUT. This can be remedied by omitting the `>> $diff.txt` part. If it also needs to be stored in file, consider the `tee` command:

  ```
  sudo diff -r dir1/ dir2/ | tee diff.txt
  ```
- When a [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) call is assigned to a variable, it will return 0 upon success. To quote the documentation:

  > The return value is the exit status of the program as returned by the [`wait`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wait.html) call.

  This means that `$diff` won't store the differences, but the command exit status. A more sensible approach would be to use backticks. Doing this will allow `$diff` to store whatever is output to STDOUT by the command:

  ```
  my $diff = `sudo diff -r dir1/ dir2/ | tee diff.txt`;  # Not $diff.txt
  ```
- Is it a must to use the `sudo` command? Avoid using it if even remotely possible:

  ```
  my $diff = `diff -r dir1/ dir2/ | tee diff.txt`;  # Not $diff.txt
  ```

**A final recommendation**

Let a good CPAN module take care of this task, as backtick calls can only go so far. Some have already been suggested here; it may be well worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

Is sudo diff being prompted for a password?
If possible, take out the sudo from the invocation of diff, and run your script with sudo.

Answer (score 0):

"It doesn't display and output." -- this is becuase you are saving the differences to a file, and then (presumably) not doing anything with that resulting file.

However, I expect "diff two directories using Perl" does not mean "use `system()` to do it in the shell and then capture the results". Have you considered doing this in the language itself? For example, see [Text::Diff](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aDiff).  For more nuanced control over what constitutes a "difference", you can simply read in each file and craft your own algorithm to perform the comparisons and compile the similarities and differences.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to check out [`Test::Differences`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3a%3aDifferences) for a more flexible diff implementation.

Comment: That module performs differences on *data structures*, not files, and within the context of a Test::Builder framework, which is entirely not what was asked for.